# How to return additional columns via SharePoint search API

Tags: search, spfx, react

I have a get request which grabs documents and saves them into state:

```
  public getDocuments() {

    axios
      .get("https://bpkintelogydev.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='owstaxIdDocumentx0020Owner0:" + this.state.selectedOption + "'&trimduplicates=true&rowsperpage=100&rowlimit=1000",
        { params:{},
          headers: { 'accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose' }
        })
      .then(response =>
          response.data.d.query.PrimaryQueryResult.RelevantResults.Table.Rows.results.map(document => ({
          Name: document.Cells.results[3].Value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + document.Cells.results[3].Value.slice(1),
          'Scheduled Review Date': '10/12/2019',
          Path: document.Cells.results[6].Value.replace('https://bpkintelogydev.sharepoint.com', ''),
          Site: document.Cells.results[36].Value.split("/").pop(),
          'Last Review Date': '25/12/2019',
          View: <a href="#" onClick={()=>window.open(document.Cells.results[6].Value + '?web=1&action=edit')}>View</a>,
          'Mark as Reviewed': <a href='#'>Mark</a>
        }))
      )
      .then(documents => {
        this.setState({
          documents, isLoading: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
      });

  }
```

I want to be able to return the columns `Last Review Date, Scheduled Review Date` as these are currently hard coded in my function above.

Using the image below which is the column settings for `Last Review Date` how would I amend my end point to include this column?

End point: `"https://bpkintelogydev.sharepoint.com/_api/search/query?querytext='owstaxIdDocumentx0020Owner0:" + this.state.selectedOption + "'&trimduplicates=true&rowsperpage=100&rowlimit=1000"`

Adding `&selectproperties='Last Review Date'` on the end does not work :/

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it will work with the "`&selectProperties='ManagedPropertyName,ManagedPropertyName2,...'`"

And that is, where your problem is. You are trying with the Display Name of the column and not the ManagedProperyName.

If you add a field (e.g: 'Last Review Date') the Sharepoint crawler will find/create a new crawled property. It will be named something like `'ows_Last_x0020_Review_x0020_Date'`. You now need to add that to a 'New Managed Property' - lets call it `'LastReviewDateMP'` - set the Type correctly and (at least) 'Retrievable' to true. In the Mappings to crawled properties you add the `'ows_Last_x0020_Review_x0020_Date'`

After you have added the new managed property and did a crawl, you could use "`&selectProperties='LastReviewDateMP'`" in your request.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: <3 thanks a lot !